# Need to serialize Any to base64 string in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, serialization

I have the following code in Kotlin which I aim to use it to convert any instance to a base64 encoded string. The same is not working and it throws the following error :

```
Serializer for class 'Any' is not found.\nMark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly
```

How can I fix this?

```
class SerializerAdapter: SerializerPort {
  private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass.simpleName)
  override fun toBase64(input: Any): String {
    try {
      val jsonString = Json.encodeToString(input)
      return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(jsonString.toByteArray())
    }catch (ex: Exception) {
      logger.error("[BASE64 Error] error converting json object to base64 encoded string: ${ex.stackTraceToString()}")
    }finally {
      return ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you plan to use `toBase64()` only with objects annotated with `@Serializable` or with any objects?

Comment: It could be with only the ones marked with @Serializable. I wouldn't if those were the only ones convertible.

Comment: Generics might be a good option here, https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#generic-functions

Comment: @undermark5 I have tried using a generic type but it asks me to get "refied" the variable

Comment: Ah, right, forgot, you'll need the have the type at runtime not just compile time. you can do `inline fun <reified T>` the downside to this is that you can only have reified type parameters on inline functions, which can have some drawbacks.

Another option is to use a Json library like Gson, Jackson, Moshi, or one of the many others, to get your json string to encode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serializing just `Any` is not as simple as it sounds. Serialization framework has to know the type of the data to serialize. It can use either compile type (`Any` in your case) or runtime type (actual type provided to `toBase64()`). Both options have their drawbacks. Runtime type is incomplete due to type erasure, so e.g. `List<Int>` and `List<String>` are the same. On the other hand, compile-time type may be totally lost, e.g. in generics or in cases like yours.

Kotlin serialization generally prefers compile types, especially because `reified` parameters make them much more usable. Unfortunately, we can't use `reified` here, because `toBase64()` is a virtual function, so it can't be inlined.

My suggestion is to change the signature of this function to additionally receive `KType` of provided data and then create inline function to make it convenient to use:

```kotlin
override fun toBase64(input: Any, type: KType): String {
    try {
        val serializer = Json.serializersModule.serializer(type)
        val jsonString = Json.encodeToString(serializer, input)
        ...
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)
inline fun <reified T>  SerializerPort.toBase64(input: Any) = toBase64(input, typeOf<T>())
```

Alternatively, we can serialize using the runtime type, but note the problems I mentioned earlier - it may not work well with generics.

```kotlin
val serializer = Json.serializersModule.serializer(input::class.starProjectedType)
val jsonString = Json.encodeToString(serializer, input)
```

Comment: Im getting this error when using your last two lines:
Star projections in type arguments are not allowed, but had java.util.ArrayList<*>\n\tat kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt__SerializersKt.serializerByKTypeImpl$SerializersKt__SerializersKt

Comment: Is it because I am using a list?

Comment: It works perfectly fine when I am passing a single item

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I mean. If you use `toBase64()` with `ArrayList` then there is no way to know what is the type inside the list. Compile type is just `Any` and runtime type is just `ArrayList`. Some serialization frameworks may be able to handle such case, by just getting the first item and then checking its runtime type. I think Kotlin serialization does not do this. You can try Jackson, but honestly, I think we should avoid such cases at all. It is better to know what we serialize and not "guess" it.

Comment: Thanks for your response then.

Comment: Anyway, first solution should work with `ArrayList` properly. If you only can change `toBase64()` signature.

Answer (score 0):

kotlinx.serialization is a *compile-time* library, so you must know up front every object you want to serialise.

Depending on your use case;

- You would either need to use a *runtime* library that uses reflection (such as one of the many JSON, or XML serialisers) to be able to use classes that are not your own.
- Or if your requirement is more that you want to be able to serialise other peoples classes then you can use your own interface that others must implement along with @Serializable (see https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1005).